# $f\left( z\right) =\log \left( \log \left( z\right) \right)$ then $f\left( z\right) =f\left( x+iy\right) =U\left( x,y\right) +i V\left( x,y\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f\left( z\right) =\log \left( \log \left( z\right) \right)$ then $f\left( z\right) =f\left( x+iy\right) =U\left( x,y\right) + iV\left( x,y\right)$ find U and V function?

I have tried harmonic and analytic function then ı got something but not specify analytic or harmonic how can ı find u and v function?I have tried polar coordinates but ı couldn't get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\log(x+iy) = \log|z|+iArg(z)  =\frac12\log(x^2 +y^2)+ i\arctan \frac{y}{x}$$
Then, 
$$\begin{align}\log \left( \log \left( z\right) \right) &=\log \left(\log|z|+iArg(z) \right) \\
&= \log\sqrt{(\log|z|)^2+(Arg(z))^2 }+ iArg(\log|z|+iArg(z)) \\&=\frac12\log\left(\left(\frac12\log(x^2 +y^2)\right)^2+\arctan^2\frac{y}{x} \right)+ i\arctan\left(\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)}{\frac12\log(x^2 +y^2)}\right).\end{align}$$

Comment: You forgot logarithm in the first square root (and all after that)

Comment: Thanks your totally right @orion

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
I learnt this approach in Milne Thomson method. Use this formula:

$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=u\{{z+\bar z \over 2},{z-\bar z \over 2i} \}+iv\{{z+\bar z \over 2},{z-\bar z \over 2i} \}$